# What is the best idea to download large files using php

Tags: php, file, upload, download

I have to download 128MB zip files from server using php. Now my question is ...

If for 10 sec net is disconnected and how can i auto resume the download process?

I have problem on large file upload and download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use FTP protocol which is able to resume the file download.

I guess this link http://www.ankur.com/blog/106/php/resume-http-downloads-php-curl-fsockopen/ could be useful for resuming the HTTP downloads. The server must implement this feature of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can use partial download method using [Content-Range and related HTTP headers](http://labs.apache.org/webarch/http/draft-fielding-http/p5-range.html).